# Stateless EJB keeping state using EJB Schedule

Tags: java, jboss7.x, cdi, ejb-3.1

I'm using JBoss AS 7 and a Schedule method on a EJB Stateless. My problem is that even the EJB is a Stateless one, its keeping its state, and this brings me trouble. Here is the example:

The timer:

```
@Stateless
public class TestTimer {

    @Inject HelloWorldService helloWorld;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*", info="MyTimer")
    private void execute() {
        System.out.println(helloWorld.sayHello());
        System.out.println(this.toString() + " "+ helloWorld.toString());
    }
}
```

The Injected HelloWorldService:

```
public class HelloWorldService {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the line `System.out.println(this.toString() + " "+ helloWorld.toString());` would print one different time every time the timer runs, since it would be a new `TestTimer` instance every time, but I was wrong:

```
16:43:50,003 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 3) foo.service.TestTimer@4a56936f foo.service.HelloWorldService@79e98289
16:44:40,022 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 1) foo.service.TestTimer@4a56936f foo.service.HelloWorldService@79e98289
```

Am I doing something wrong, this is the expected behavior, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters is that each timer there is a lookup, you may get a different instance of the bean 
,
but "may" means you may still get the same instance, as it is obtained from a pool of beans 
That the container manages for you. 
There is nothing wrong with using the same timer object, 
as long as it provides the proper functionality. 
This means that as a developer you cannot make any assumption on the state of the bean, and whether or not it is will be restored upon a new lookup of the bean.

Comment: All were good answers and helped me understand a little about my problem. I'll accept yours because it describes better for me about the case

Answer (score 2):

The EJB specification doesn't state that stateless beans *discard* their state after each invocation. It states that application developers must not rely on the bean *keeping* its state. There's a subtle, but very important difference. The same bean instance may be used multiple times; this doesn't negate stateless-ness.

Comment: in fact it requires it.  the fact is that any state would have to be considered "spurious" because of the lack of contract (stateless beans may be pooled as needed by the container, per the spec).

Comment: @him I'm not sure what had changed in the six years since I posted this answer. Are EJB containers are now required to explicitly discard stateless beans' state after each method invocation?

Comment: not required to discard it, but not guaranteed to maintain it.  remember, for a SLSB, "this" points to a proxy, not the concrete implementation.  for instance, if you have SLAB a and b (two instances in a pool of same EJB type), a call from a.method1() to a.method2() might be answered by "b" because the container is free to optimize its calls however it sees fit.  you have no guarantee who answers the call, just that it is an instance of that type from a pool (that might only contain 1 instance under light load).

Answer (score 1):

The stateless beans can be used as many times as it needed. They are not neccecary created every time. You can look at EJB LifeCycle at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior (per Java EE specs) and is actually a bit more complicated than that.

The app server is managing a pool of staless session beans and using instances from this pool in order to server client requests. If you have some load on the server, then several beans will be used from the pool and each one will have its own state. So, in your test, you would end having sometimes the same string value printed, sometimes another one being printed.

You should not use properties for business logic. However, using properties for technical purposes (e.g. keep a reference to a DB) is sometimes a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The container has a pool of stateless session beans.
It is internal to the container to handle the number of instances active (as far as i know)
For your case it seems same instance is called by the timer.